# How can I stop redirecting from a search to a taxonomy archive page

Tags: redirect, search, archives

I have a search form that searches through custom taxonomies, but instead of printing the results on the search page it redirects to the taxonomy archive. I leave the url before and after the redirect to explain myself better. How can I disable the redirect?

SEARCH
/?area=tuscany&guests_2=0%3B50&post_type=property

REDIRECT AFTER SEARCH
/area/tuscany/?guests_2=0%3B50&post_type=property

Comment: neither of those URLs are search URLs, but I can guess from the second URL that you have a taxonomy named `area`? If so then `/area/tuscany` translates to the ugly permalink `index.php?area=tuscany` which is identical to your original search URL, WP isn't redirecting you to a new page, it's enforcing the pretty permalink for the page you told it you wanted. Remember, the query parameters that go into the main `WP_Query` come from the URL, pretty permalinks just hide those behind a nice URL with regular expressions that convert it from `/foo/bar` to `index.php?foo=bar`

Comment: TLDR the search URL in its current form cannot be saved, nor should it be saved, it _must_ be changed, either to not use `area` as a URL parameter, or to include other parameters. Also that is not a search page, there is no `s` parameter and no `search.php`. By calling it a search page you may confuse people who are expecting things such as `is_search` to be true etc